Local volatility from stochastic volatility: implications for hedging
This is something I've been wondering about:
Given a stochastic volatility model with (stochastic) spot variance $\sigma^2_t$, according to Gyöngy's theorem there exists a local volatility $\sigma^2(K,T) = E_t [\sigma_T^2 | S_T = K ]$ such that the terminal distributions of $S_T$ are equal under
$$
dS_t = \sigma_t S_t dW_t, \quad (1)
$$
and
$$
dS_t = \sigma(S_t,t) S_t dW_t, \quad (2)
$$
As the distribution of $S_T$ is the same for both processes, the price of an option $(S_T - K)_+$ is the same for both processes. Since the price is the replicating portfolio, this means that delta-vega hedging the option under (1) should be the same cost as delta-hedging the option under (2) (strictly speaking no vega hedge in local vol).
Is this correct? If so is there a way to prove this other than by the arbitrage argument above?
